# How to show camera overlay only in landscape on iPad

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am working on a Titanium app for iPad and I am supporting all screen orientations, but I have custom overlay on the camera which I want to be displayed only in landscape left orientation. I tried with setting orientationModes:[Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT] but that has no effect. Every time I change the orientation the overlay is rotating. 
My question is how can I lock the window orientation in landscape mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with adding the following in your tiapp.xml file?

```
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array> 
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        </array>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in the tiapp.xml I have all orientations enabled, and I want just the camera overlay to be displayed in landscape.
 <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
        <array> 
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        </array>